# Nested class, dllexport and VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, nested-class, dllexport, explicit-instantiation

Let's have the following code:

```
template <typename T> struct X
{ X() { }
};

struct __declspec(dllexport) A
{ struct __declspec(dllexport) AB
  { int i;
  };

  typedef X <AB> XAB;

  //template struct __declspec(dllexport) X <AB>; // error C2252: an explicit instantiation of a template can only occur at namespace scope

  static XAB x; // warning C4251: 'A::x' : struct 'X<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'A'
  static X <AB> x2; // warning C4251: 'A::x2' : struct 'X<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'A'
  X <AB> x3; // warning C4251: 'A::x3' : struct 'X<T>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of struct 'A'
};

template struct __declspec(dllexport) X <A::AB>; // Has no effect
```

So:

- I have a class to be exported to a DLL.
- This class has a subclass to be exported to the DLL, too.
- There are variables ('x...') of type `template <subclass>`.
- The member variables need to be dll-exported, too.
- So I'd need to instantiate explicitly the `template <subclass>` before this type is used.
- But this is not possible as instantiation may be done only in the global scope.
- But in the global scope, the subclass is not defined (yet).
- The `template <class::subclass>` instantiation after the class body has no effect.

So how to handle this problem correctly, to avoid any warnings and errors?

BTW: Instantiation of template  within the class worked well in VS2008.

Thank you in advance.

LuP